# Error al pedir datos a MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

estoy intentando extraer datos de mongoDb, con ( moongose , nodejs )...
ya me he conectado correctamente a la base de datos, y ya tengo una collection creada.
para esa collection, tengo 1 model en el file ( models/candidates.js ) :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const candidatesSchema = new Schema({
    Login: String,
    BehaviorPoints: Number,
    Note: String
});

const Candidates = mongoose.model('Candidates', candidatesSchema);
module.exports = Candidates;
```

entonces estoy intentando usar ese modelo desde ( server.js ) file :

```
/* Database */
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Candidates } = require('./models/candidates');
```

Here is my connection to the database:

```
    async _connectDB() {

        const dbUser = process.env.DBUSER;;
        const dbPassword = process.env.DBPASSWORD;
        const dbName = process.env.DBNAME;
        const dbUri = `mongodb+srv://${dbUser}:${dbPassword}@********.dzae0.mongodb.net/${dbName}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

        mongoose.connect(dbUri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } )
        .then( () => console.log(clc.cyan('Debug: Database connected successfully')))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
```

y esta es la forma en la que estoy intentando extraer esa informacion:

```
        app.get("/candidates", async (req, res, next) => {
            if (req.originalUrl.startsWith("/404")) {
                return error();
            }
            try {
                const arrayCandidatesDB = await Candidates.find();
                res.send(arrayCandidatesDB);
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(clc.red(err));
            }
        });
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
Debug: Server listening on port 3001
Debug: Database connected successfully
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find').
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No requieres los corchetes:

```
const { Candidates } = require('./models/candidates');
//Sin los corchetes
const  Candidates  = require('./models/candidates');
```

Al hacer el `module.exports` (la exportación por default) toma todos los parámetros y funciones del objeto exportado. Acceder con los corchetes solo es necesario si quieres acceder a una función ó propiedad. Algo como: `const { find } = require('./models/candidates');`. Lo que haría que la variable find fuera la función `find` de `candidates`. Algo muy extraño a simple vista, pero en ciertas importaciones muy funcional. (Aunque no es tu caso)

Comment: Funciona!, muchas gracias por la explicación.